# How to access component from one mxml to another or all mxml files in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox

I have following code, I want to access this combobox & combobox value to other mxml file, but it got null. How to access this combobox to other mxml file?
Please help me.
Thanks,
Nitin

---

### Control.mxml

```
<mx:ComboBox id="comboBox" name="comboBox1" dataProvider="{_pageIndexArray}" change="jumpToPage();" accessibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the ComboBox?  What is your hierarchy? Does this blog post help? http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a good way to access components of other mxml file.Here are two ways to access the combobox data.

1. add some common functions that manipulate combobox in A mxml,like

   ```
   function getSelectedIndex():int

   function getSelectedData():Object
   ```

   so you could access the data like

   ```
   var index:int = a.getSelectedIndex();//a is an instance of A mxml
   ```
2. add a notify function in A mxml, When the combobox changes(like dataChange, or selected item change, the notify function will be called.

   You can use signal framework  [as3 signal](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a public variable on the file which the combobox resides, code var abcComboBoxSelectedValue:String = abcCombobox.selectedItem.label; Then, use that variable.